# How to display simple modal with ng-bootstrap (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a simple Modal with Ng2-bootstrap as per the following page: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

However I am getting errors such as:

`Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:7:0 caused by: Missing modal container, add <template ngbModalContainer></template> to one of your application templates.`

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Missing modal container, add <template ngbModalContainer></template> to one of your application templates.`

**What am I doing wrong?** I've got the following code to try and make this work:

**Index.html:**

`<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <template ngbModalContainer></template>
 </body>`

**app.module.ts:**

`import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot() ...`

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SasModalComponent } from './sas-modal/sas-modal.component';
...
constructor(..., private modalService: NgbModal){
}
...
open() {
  console.log("trying to open");
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(SasModalComponent);
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**sas-modal.component.ts**

```
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'sas-modal',
  templateUrl: './sas-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sas-modal.component.css']
})
export class SasModalComponent {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
}
```

**sas-modal.component.html:**

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Add  entryComponents: [SasModalComponent]  in your appModule file in @NgModule()

Comment: Your constructor() in sas-modal.component.ts should be  :-      constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal){}. Dont pass modalService in the constructor it and no need to declare the open function in sas-modal.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

sas-component.ts should be : -

```
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'sas-modal',
  templateUrl: './sas-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sas-modal.component.css']
})
export class SasModalComponent {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

}
```

app.module.ts Should contain SasModuleComponent in the declaration array and a
entryComponent field that contains SasModuleComponent : -

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,
   FormsModule , HttpModule, NgbModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, SasModalComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [SasModalComponent]
})
```

You need a entryComponent field in @NgModule()in your module file because you are loading the SasModuleComponent dynamically here `this.modalService.open(SasModalComponent)`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped to get me closer to the answer, but was not the answer completely, you've got a couple of things wrong, will post the answer tomorrow :)

Comment: @MikeDub  What is wrong in this? This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<template ngbModalContainer></template>` in app-root template

**Example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<template ngbModalContainer></template>'
})
```

Comment: Example: @Component({ selector: 'app-root', template: '`<template ngbModalContainer></template>`' })

Comment: That doesn't work, it doesn't display anything on the page then

Comment: Step 1: sas-modal.component.html

Comment: Don't use template in sas-modal.component.html. See bootstrap demo [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ub40dw7BLQNwkz7FjLHR?p=preview)

Comment: Adding `entryComponents: [SasModalComponent],` in your `@NgModule`

Answer (score 0):

**saurav1405**'s answer provided me with enough useful information to figure this out, however his solution didn't 100% work for me.

For this reason I've upvoted **saurav1405**'s response, but couldn't claim is as the answer as I've had to do a bit more to get it to work for me.

*The main difference was having a seperate control component and content component.*

This is how I got it working:

**>> app.module.ts**

Note: **saurav1405** suggested putting ***ModalContentComponent*** into **declarations**, [image: saurav1405 ModalContentComponent] *(possibly a typo after reviewing his comments again).*

but you need to put the actual modal custom modal components in here (in this case **SasModalComponent** & **SasModalContent**).

And the content component (**SasModalContent**) needs to be the entry component.

```
import { SasModalComponent, SasModalContent } from './sas-modal/sas-modal.component';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SasModalComponent,
    SasModalContent
  ],
  entryComponents: [SasModalContent],
...
```

**>> app.component.html:**

The **ngbModalContainer** declaration should be along side the component declaration in the parent component html template, not in the index.html, which I think was the main reason I was getting the errors posted in the question.

```
<template ngbModalContainer></template>
<sas-modal-component></sas-modal-component>
```

**>> sas-modal.component.ts:**

This file combines both the control component **[sas-modal-component]** (that opens the content / template) and the content component **[sas-modal-content]** (that has the reference to the active modal and modal template).

```
import {Component, Input, Compiler } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'sas-modal-content',
  templateUrl: 'sas-modal-content.html'
})
export class SasModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sas-modal-component',
  templateUrl: 'sas-modal.component.html'
})
export class SasModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private compiler: Compiler) {  }

  open() {
    //this.compiler.clearCacheFor(SasModalContent); //Only use when the template is caching when you don't want it to.
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(SasModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```

**>> sas-modal.component.html:** *Contains the button / control to open the modal*

```
<h2> Click the button to open the modal</h2>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**>> sas-modal-content.html:** *Holds the modal template - can be whatever you want*

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body card-info">
    <h3 style="color: white;">So nice to meet you</h3>
    <h4 style="color: white;">This modal is great!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer ">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes there was a typo in declaration. I have edited that in the answer.